# How to get max value from one table, then join another table using Entity Framework 6

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 tables `stock` and `stockprice`. I want to get all stocks with their last updated price using Entity Framework 6.

I first `select * from stock`, then use foreach to get last updated price for each symbol. How can do that with just one query using entity framework 6?

**Stock**:

```
Id    Symbol
-------------
1     AAPL
2     MSFT
```

**Stockprice**:

```
Id   Symbol   Price   LastUpdatedDate    
-------------------------------------
1    AAPL      120    11/7/2016
2    AAPL      121    11/2/2016
3    AAPL      123    11/3/2016
4    MSFT      111    11/2/2016
5    MSFT      101    11/6/2016
```

I want to get last updated price for each symbol.

```
AAPL  120  11/7/2016
MSFT  101  11/6/2016
```

Comment: Let me know if you are ok with using either Stored Procedures or views to get the desired results (which you can then call from Entity Framework)

Comment: @objectNotFound, i prefer not to use SP or Views. but if its too hard to do it using entity framework, I am open to SP.

Comment: It is sooooo easy to do this in a SP or View ... IMHO this should be the right way to do this. I will post the query and you can decide if you want to keep it as a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have list of object with property
Id,Symbol,Price,LastUpdatedDate

let say

```
List<ItemPrice> itemPrice
```

then you can do like this

```
    var lastUpdated= from item in itemPrice
                group item by item.Symbol into itemGroup
                let maxDate = itemGroup.Max(gt => gt.LastUpdatedDate)
                select new RegistrationModel
                        {
                            Symbol = itemGroup.Key,
                            LastUpdatedDate= maxDate,
                            Price= itemGroup.First(gt2 => gt2.ExpiryDateAD == maxDate).Price
}).ToList()
```

i hope it may help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using(var db= new DbContext())
{
    //This will fetch all your stock and include all corresponding StockPrices. 
    var stockWithPrices = db.Stock
                            .Select(x=> new 
                            {
                               Name = x. Name
      Price = x.StockPrices.OrderByDescending(y=>y.LastUpdatedDate).FirstOrDefault().Price
      Date = x.StockPrices.OrderByDescending(y=>y.LastUpdatedDate).FirstOrDefault().Date
                            }.ToList();
}
```

Assuming your model look like this

```
public partial class  Stock
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Symbol {get;set;}
   public ICollection<StockPrice> StockPrices {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I realize you prefer a pure EF solution but this is another way to do it and I think it will be more scalable and supportable.

**Query** :

```
Select A.Symbol, C.Price, A.MaxDate
(
Select Max(LastUpdatedDate) as MaxDate, Symbol 
FROM stockprice A INNER JOIN stock B on A.Symbol = B.Symbol
Group By Symbol
) A 
INNER JOIN StockPrice C on  A.Symbol = C.Symbol AND A.MaxDate = C.LastUpdatedDate
```

**To make a View** :

```
Create View vStockPrice AS
Select A.Symbol, C.Price, A.MaxDate
(
Select Max(LastUpdatedDate) as MaxDate, Symbol 
FROM stockprice A INNER JOIN stock B on A.Symbol = B.Symbol
Group By Symbol
) A 
INNER JOIN StockPrice C on  A.Symbol = C.Symbol AND A.MaxDate = C.LastUpdatedDate
Go
```

**To Do it using Stored Procedures:**

```
Create Procedure usp_StockPrice AS
Begin
Select A.Symbol, C.Price, A.MaxDate
(
Select Max(LastUpdatedDate) as MaxDate, Symbol 
FROM stockprice A INNER JOIN stock B on A.Symbol = B.Symbol
Group By Symbol
) A 
INNER JOIN StockPrice C on  A.Symbol = C.Symbol AND A.MaxDate = C.LastUpdatedDate
END
```

Then  you simply query the view like you would query any table using EF or use the process to call a stored procedure.

```
var query = from rows in vStockPrice select ..... ;
```

The advantage of doing it in View or SP is that you can handle any future changes to your requirements by simply altering the base query. (Say you want to ignore penny stocks so all it will take is a where clause : where price > 1.0 ). You will not have to recompile your C# code (and your DBA will like this approach for other reasons !!)

Let me know if you want me to expand (or you think this is not relevant )